# iterating over a deque in two directions efficiently in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a deque, let's call it `deq`. I need to iterate over it from both ends, and I will not be modifying it at all during these iterations.

Naturally, I don't want to create *another* deque.
I've considered `reversed`, but I don't know if it actually creates any copies. If, for example, I were write:

```
reversed_deq = reversed(deq)
```

will it reference the exact same memory locations, but simply iterate over it in reverse, without using any more memory/time?

That seems like the logical way to go for a double-ended queue, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

I can't find the code for deque (usually they have a "python equivalent" of these things, but I couldn't find it), and for some reason - no matter what I run - `timeit` always gives me something between 15 and 16 ns (for everything I try to time, not just this)

Comment: In python you use list for deque, there is no need for anything else. Also, if you want do do something efficienly, you should not use Python for that.

Comment: @HannesKarppila Unfortunately, I have no choice but to use Python, so I'm making the best of a bad situation. And there is no reason for me to use lists, since A. I constantly add elements to the deque, and a list gets reallocated every time, and B. I only need to access the first elements, and - at most - the last 3 elements.

Comment: collections.deque has a built in reverse() method. When you say iterate over it from both ends do you mean iterate once in one direction, then once in the other?

Comment: @csunday95 Yes. I've read the documentation, it says "in place" - which (from what I understand) means without needing to reallocate memory. I just want to verify that they don't also iterate over all the deque and reverse the order (since, from what I understand, each element points to the next and previous element in the implementation). As I've mentioned, I can't find the actual code for the deque, and my `timeit` function doesn't appear to work properly.

Comment: what operation are you trying to do in both directions?

Comment: @csunday95 just iterate and look at each element. I don't modify it or anything, and since I need to iterate over the elements in order anyway, I figured there has to be a better way than doing `for i in xrange(len(deq)): deq[i],deq[-1*i -1]`

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c for the source code. Looks like to reverse it iterates over the linked list (which is made up of blocks) and swaps the order around two at a time from either end. Why not use a list in this case?

Comment: @csunday95 as I've mentioned, I constantly add elements to the list. I don't know how many elements I will add until I'm done, and I don't want to reallocate space over and over again. Only when I'm done I iterate over the deque

Comment: If you want to use collections.deque, `i = reversed(my_deque)` might be useful. It gives you an iterator that starts at the last element. Calling `i.next()` iterates toward the first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [C source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ef633e5000222a3dba74473c49d6a81fca0a44ec/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L1820) `reversed([deque])` returns a reverse iterator, no copies or memory allocation. `[deque].reverse()` will reverse it in place.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I failed to find the source code. Although you linked to the implementation of 3.5, I changed the link to 2.7 and it worked :)

Comment: Ah didn't notice that, seems like something that wouldn't have changed luckily.

Answer (score 1):

[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) and [3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) documentation states that the `reversed()` built-in function “returns a reverse [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-iterator)”. Strictly speaking, this does not prevent an implementation of `collections.deque.__reversed__()` to make copies. In practice, there is no reason why it would make copies, since a deque is naturally iterable in both directions.